# Text Reader Classes in Hadoop

Tags: io, hadoop

I have a directory OUTPUT where I have the output files from a Map Reduce job. The output files are Text files written with a TextOutputFormat.

Now I want to read the key value pairs from the output file. How can I do so using some existing classes in hadoop. One way I could do it was as follows

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
FileStatus[] files = fs.globStatus(new Path(OUTPUT + "/part-*"));
for(FileStatus file:files){
  if(file.getLen() > 0){
    FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(file.getPath());
    BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        in));
    String s = bin.readLine();
    while(s!=null){
      System.out.println(s);
      s = bin.readLine();
    }
    in.close();
  }
}
```

This approach would work but increases my task to a great deal as I now need to manually parse the key value pairs out of each individual line. I am looking for something more handy that directly lets me read key and value in some variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you forced to use `TextOutputFormat` as your output format in the previous job?

If not then consider using SequenceFileOutputFormat, then you can use a SequenceFile.Reader to read back the file in Key / Value pairs. You can also still 'view' the file using `hadoop fs -text path/to/output/part-r-00000`

**EDIT**: You can also use the `KeyValueLineRecordReader` class, you'll just need to pass in a FileSplit to teh constructor.

Comment: I am using TextOutputFormat because I need the output files to be human readable. I already considered what you suggested, thanks though, that would be my last resort.